# Is cheque and check interchangeable when referencing a checking account?

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Checking” vs. “chequing” vs. “chequeing” with regards to types of bank accounts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16749/checking-vs-chequing-vs-chequeing-with-regards-to-types-of-bank-accounts)
>   [Do we ask for check or cheque in restaurants?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57308/do-we-ask-for-check-or-cheque-in-restaurants)

I believe the original spelling for it was cheque, but when used in context of an account, it appears to the the form of check.  **Are these two words interchangeable or is there some background story as the two spellings?**

Comment: See possible duplicate [Do we ask for check or cheque in restaurants](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57308)  and also see [Why is a restaurant bill called a check](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46251), and also [Checking vs chequing vs chequeing with regards to types of bank accounts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16749),

Comment: @jwpat7 Only partially, but thanks for pointing it out.  But in the british financial instrument context, is it still called a "checking account".

Comment: Which is at variance with Tim Lymington's answer. (?)

Comment: @jwpat7 Ok, you win.  I've duped.

Comment: ... only if *color* and *colour* are interchangeable when you tell your bank what you want your checks/cheques to look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In British English, *cheque* is the only spelling for the financial instrument; what you get in a restaurant is the *bill*.  In American English, *check* is used for both.